# Error when clicking AlertDialog to setValue at Firebase database

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to select an option at AlertDialog but it shows an error. Below is the error:

```
10-17 00:54:44.765 25600-25600/com.example.jingwen.bluetoothlowenergy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jingwen.bluetoothlowenergy, PID: 25600
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.example.jingwen.bluetoothlowenergy.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:325)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:959)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3063)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3881)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

This is the code where the error occurs, specifically the setValue part to Firebase database :

```js
private void alertdialog()
    {
        final CharSequence peers[] = new CharSequence[] {"Home", "School", "Children"};
        stopScan();
        final String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        if(alert11!=null && alert11.isShowing()) return;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("Add this device to peer list?");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                "Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder pbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        pbuilder.setTitle("Set peer as:");
                        pbuilder.setCancelable(false);
                        pbuilder.setItems(peers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // the user clicked on option[which]
                                if(which == 0) {
                                    databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child("Peer list").child(mBTDevicesArrayList.get(post).getAddress()).setValue("Home");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Set peer as 'Home'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Peer list updated!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                if(which == 1) {
                                    databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child("Peer list").child(mBTDevicesArrayList.get(post).getAddress()).setValue("School");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Set peer as 'School'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Peer list updated!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                if(which == 2) {
                                    databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child("Peer list").child(mBTDevicesArrayList.get(post).getAddress()).setValue("Children");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Set peer as 'Children'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Peer list updated!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        pbuilder.show();

                    }
                });
```

Do tell me if there are more parts of the codes need to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely has nothing to do with Firebase.

As far as I can tell, mBTDevicesArrayList (definition and assignment not shown above) is an ArrayList of size zero, and you're passing a value of 1 to its get method,as indicated by the error message "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0".  The line numbers in the stack trace will help you figure out which one of the three instances you're showing.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, there are issues at my ArrayList.